Cannot insert PSOT data in SQLlite3 db in Django - NOT NULL constraint failed error
EDIT: Fixed null error as suggested.  However, when trying to get the data, all that was entered into the answers table was a single blank entry.  So I decided to use a form but that generated a new error:
<ul class="errorlist"><li>name<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>value<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>

forms.py
    class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
          model = Answer
          fields = ["name", "value"]

views.py snippets:
def leadership(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    #results=dict(request.POST) # get POST data from form
    #print("Post", results)
    form = AnswerForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        value =  request.POST.get('value')
        answer = Answer(name=name, value=value)
        print(answer)
        answer.save()
        # everything belwo here is just to calculate a score and render an anser page with color coding based on score
        score_comments=create_list(results) #Get tuple with (score, comments)
        score=score_comments[0]
        comments=score_comments[1]
        question_answers = []
        question_answers =  score_comments[2]
        results_color = score_color(score)
        print(score, results_color,comments, question_answers)
        #answers(results)
        context = {
            "shade": results_color
        }
        return render(request, "leadershipresults.html", context)
    else:
            print("Form not valid")
            print(form.errors)
            return render(request, "leadership.html")
        
else:
        print("No POST Request")
        return render(request, "leadership.html")

models.py:
class Answer(models.Model):
value = models.IntegerField(null = True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null = True)
# q_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="XX")  # USed foreignkey instead
question = models.ForeignKey(
    Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null  = True
)


def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.question} value is {self.value}"


Original Post:
I have a page with 10 questions and a comment field.  The questions' answers are selected via are radio buttons, the comment is a text field.  When I tr to get the POST data entered into my SQL data base I get the error:
NOT NULL constraint failed: ISO22301_answer.value

The SQL table has 3 fields:
Name - an identifier from LQ1 to LQ10
Answer - integer from 0 - 5
Question - a FK that has the text of the question being answered. Since the questions are in teh db when I g to admin they show up as a drop down in answer.
The relevant file snippets are:
models.py
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)  # THis is probably useless

    topic = models.ForeignKey(
        Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )  # Django will store this as topic_id on database

class Answer(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # q_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="XX")  # USed foreignkey instead
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.question} value is {self.value}"

leadership.html (one of the 10 rows):
  <td colspan="7">Risk Assessment and Planning</td>
  <tr>
      <td class="question">Conducts annual risk assesments and identifies key risks and mitigation actions</td>
      <td>
        <input  name="LQ1" type="radio" value="1" id="LQ1_1" />1
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="LQ1" type="radio" value="2" id="LQ1_2" />2
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="LQ1" type="radio" value="3"  id="LQ1_3"/>3
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="LQ1" type="radio" value="4"  id="LQ1_4"/>4
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="LQ1" type="radio" value="5"  id="LQ1_5"/>5
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="LQ1" type="radio" value="0"  id="LQ1_6"/>
    </td>
  </tr>

views.py:
def leadership(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        results=dict(request.POST) # get POST data from form
        print("Post", results)
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        value =  request.POST.get('value')
        answer = Answer(name=name, value=value)
        answer.save()
        # everything belwo here is just to calculate a score and render an anser page with color coding based on score
        score_comments=create_list(results) #Get tuple with (score, comments)
        score=score_comments[0]
        comments=score_comments[1]
        question_answers = []
        question_answers =  score_comments[2]
        results_color = score_color(score)
        print(score, results_color,comments, question_answers)
        #answers(results)
        context = {
            "shade": results_color
        }
        return render(request, "leadershipresults.html", context)
    else:
        return render(request, "leadership.html")

POST Data returned:

Variable        Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken 'mR6idvTRbovOc1V24ZcyJsosXaylGQx4SZ4f99BlAQ2gvJkwK7LfhxMJMYjr3bAo'
LQ1         '2'
LQ2         '2'
LQ3         '2'
LQ4         '2'
LQ5         '2'
LQ6         '2'
LQ7         '2'
LQ8         '2'
LQ9         '2'
LQ10            '2'
L_Text          'nmbvbncvbcxv'

SQL tables
ISO22301_answer             auth_user                 
ISO22301_area               auth_user_groups          
ISO22301_comment            auth_user_user_permissions
ISO22301_question           django_admin_log          
ISO22301_topic              django_content_type       
auth_group                  django_migrations         
auth_group_permissions      django_session            
auth_permission

sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(ISO22301_answer);
0|id|INTEGER|1||1
1|value|INTEGER|1||0
2|name|varchar(20)|1||0
3|question_id|bigint|1||0

I tried removing the Token and Comments from the returned POST data and the doing get() but that didn't work.
I used pop and del to do that.
I also tried adding "blank=True, null=True" to
class Answer(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # q_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="XX")  # USed foreignkey instead
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

to no avail.

You need to change the value field of your answer model.
class Answer(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
=>
value = models.IntegerField(null=True)
OR
value = models.IntegerField(default=984354684)


Made the change but get same error

don't forget migrate after change model.

Yup, I forgot. The error went away but all it posted was a single blank value in the DB.  Tried using forms but get an invalid form.  Edited to show what I tried with forms.py
